# i want to create a drop down menu for blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, blogger

i want to create an dropp down menu for blogger using underscore menu system

i found this code on web : `$("#LinkList1").each(function(){var e="<ul id='nav'><li><ul id='sub-menu'>";$("#LinkList1 li").each(function(){var t=$(this).text(),n=t.substr(0,1),r=t.substr(1);"_"==n?(n=$(this).find("a").attr("href"),e+='<li><a href="'+n+'">'+r+"</a></li>"):(n=$(this).find("a").attr("href"),e+='</ul></li><li><a href="'+n+'">'+t+"</a><ul id='sub-menu'>")});e+="</ul></li></ul>";$(this).html(e);$("#LinkList1 ul").each(function(){var e=$(this);if(e.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g,"").length==0)e.remove()});$("#LinkList1 li").each(function(){var e=$(this);if(e.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g,"").length==0)e.remove()})});`   i want an additional js code that he check if a li element contains a sub menu , if true , add a classname to this specific li

Comment: Please provide a functional code sample that clearly describes what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, and what is not working as expected. Stack Overflow is a place to seek out programming advice and assistance, not to have others complete your work for you.